# Fourier series converges "almost everywhere"

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series, baire-category, almost-everywhere

I'm reading "Fourier series" by Rajendra Bhatia.
At one point, the author says:

"[..]*one can show the existence of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges except on a set of points of the first* (Baire) *category in T* (the circle)*, and the existence of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges on an uncountable set.*"

But, thanks to the Carleson-Hunt theorem we know that:

"[..]*if f* (a function) *is continuous. then its Fourier series converges almost everywhere.*"

(from the same book)

Isn't there a contradiction?

Thanks in advance for the answers!!

Comment: A set of first category (aka a meager set) can have a complement of zero measure. See e.g. question/answer 7 here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~sarason/Class_Webpages/solutions_202B_assign2.pdf Also, an uncountable set can have measure zero, e.g. the Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was searching for!